# How to extract tuples using findall?

Tags: python, regex, findall

I'm trying to extract tuples from an **url** and I've managed to extract *string text* and *tuples* using the `re.search(pattern_str, text_str)`. However, I got stuck when I tried to extract a list of tuples using `re.findall(pattern_str, text_str)`.

The text looks like:

```
<li>
  <a href="11111">
    some text 111
    <span class="some-class">
      #11111
    </span>
  </a>
</li><li>
  <a href="22222">
    some text 222
    <span class="some-class">
      #22222
    </span>
  </a>
</li><li>
  <a href="33333">
    some text 333
    <span class="some-class">
      #33333
    </span>
  </a>
... # repeating
... 
...
```

and I'm using the following pattern & code to extract the tuples:

```
text_above = "..." # this is the text above
pat_str = '<a href="(\d+)">\n(.+)\n<span class'
pat = re.compile(pat_str)
# following line is supposed to return the numbers from the 2nd line
# and the string from the 3rd line for each repeating sequence
list_of_tuples = re.findall(pat, text_above)

for t in list_of tuples:
    # supposed to print "11111 -> blah blah 111"
    print(t[0], '->', t[1])
```

Maybe I'm trying something weird & impossible, maybe its better to extract the data using primitive string manipulations... But in case there exists a solution?

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regular expressions. Use a parser like beautiful soup!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, use a html parser like [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

h = """<li>
  <a href="11111">
    some text 111
    <span class="some-class">
      #11111
    </span>
  </a>
</li><li>
  <a href="22222">
    some text 222
    <span class="some-class">
      #22222
    </span>
  </a>
</li><li>
  <a href="33333">
    some text 333
    <span class="some-class">
      #33333
    </span>
  </a>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(h)
```

You can get the href and the previous_sibling to the span:

```
print([(a["href"].strip(), a.span.previous_sibling.strip()) for a in soup.find_all("a")])
[('11111', u'some text 111'), ('22222', u'some text 222'), ('33333', u'some text 333')]
```

Or the href and the first content from the anchor:

```
print([(a["href"].strip(), a.contents[0].strip()) for a in soup.find_all("a")])
```

Or with `.find(text=True)` to only get the tag text and not from the children.

```
[(a["href"].strip(), a.find(text=True).strip()) for a in soup.find_all("a")]
```

Also if you just want the anchors inside the list tags, you can specifically parse those:

```
[(a["href"].strip(), a.contents[0].strip()) for a in soup.select("li a")]
```

Comment: Well, my intention was to learn & get used to `re.search()` & `re.findall()`. I know I could get around easily using `bs4`, but I'll give it a try some other time (after learning *regex*).

Comment: It made me pull out my hair but finally I did it with **regex**. However, to be fair, when I gave it a try w/ **bs4**... Voila! That's time saving like no other. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex does not take into account the whitespace (indentation) between `\n` and `<span`. (And neither the whitespace at the start of the line you want to capture, but that's not as much of a problem.) To fix it, you could add some `\s*`:

```
pat_str = '<a href="(\d+)">\n\s*(.+)\n\s*<span class'
```

Comment: Well... That's my fault. It seemed a reasonable solution; so, I've tried `pat_str = '<a href="(\d+)">[\n\s]*(.+)[\n\s]*<span class'`. This time the code entered into the for loop but print the whole text; not in tuples. That is, list contained only one element. Is there something wrong int the `print` part of the code.

Comment: @merkez3110 By default, regex behaves greedily. The way you did it, it will try to find the largest possible match, and that match will span from the first `href` to the last `span`. Either make those non-greedy with `*?` instead of `*` or just use my variant.

Comment: Now I'm getting somewhere... Just a last question if you don't mind: Is it a better solution to use the `re.DOTALL` in the compile statement or should I leave it to the `\n` characters?

Comment: @merkez3110 Yes, you could probably also use `re.DOTALL` with a regex like `'<a href="(\d+)">(.+)<span class'` and strip the whitespace around the second group afterwards. This way the whitespace in the HTML is not as significant (at least not in that place).